# Read Merged Cell From Excel Using oledb

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oledb

I am using oledb to read .xls files in my application. It is working fine but real issue comes when my excel contains merged cells in rows or in column.

This is the data in excel

[image: excel data]

This is how it show on screen using webgrid

[image: output using webgrid]

Comment: Merged cells breaks the paradigm of tabular structure of a table. Simply we don't have any information for the merged cells but the first one. How do you propose to re-add the missing info?

Comment: @steve I want to read merged cells from excel and show them exactly how they appear in excel. in above example i can modify UI with the help of CSS but i want this dynamic. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The VERY first thing that I would say is STAY VERY FAR AWAY FROM MERGED CELLS IN EXCEL!!  That is the work of the DEVIL.  Ok, if you still want to do this, consider the following options (you don't have many options) . . .

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace Detect_Merged_Cells
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile("Sample.xlsx");
            Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            CellRange[] range = sheet.MergedCells;
            foreach (CellRange cell in range)
            {
                cell.UnMerge();
            }
            workbook.SaveToFile("Output.xlsx",ExcelVersion.Version2010);
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
Excel.Range firstCell = excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
Excel.Range lastCell = excelWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

object[,] cellValues;
object[,] cellFormulas;

Excel.Range worksheetCells = excelWorksheet.get_Range(firstCell, lastCell);
cellValues = worksheetCells.Value2 as object[,];
cellFormulas = worksheetCells.Formula as object[,];
```